# Collatz conjecture in R

Tags: python, r, collatz

I am still teaching some R mainly to myself (and to my students).

Here's an implementation of the Collatz sequence in R:

```
f <- function(n)
{
    # construct the entire Collatz path starting from n
    if (n==1) return(1)
    if (n %% 2 == 0) return(c(n, f(n/2)))
    return(c(n, f(3*n + 1)))
}
```

Calling f(13) I get
13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1

However note that a vector is growing dynamically in size here. Such moves tend to be a recipe for inefficient code. Is there a more efficient version?

In Python I would use

```
def collatz(n):
    assert isinstance(n, int)
    assert n >= 1

    def __colla(n):

        while n > 1:
            yield n

            if n % 2 == 0:
                n = int(n / 2)
            else:
                n = int(3 * n + 1)

        yield 1

    return list([x for x in __colla(n)])
```

I found a way to write into vectors without specifying their dimension a priori. Therefore a solution could be

```
collatz <-function(n)
{
  stopifnot(n >= 1)  
  # define a vector without specifying the length
  x = c()

  i = 1
  while (n > 1)
  {
    x[i] = n
    i = i + 1
    n = ifelse(n %% 2, 3*n + 1, n/2)
  }
  x[i] = 1
  # now "cut" the vector
  dim(x) = c(i)
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: [a-look-a-r-vectorization-through-the-collatz-conjecture](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/04/a-look-a-r-vectorization-through-the-collatz-conjecture.html)

Comment: [r-and-the-collatz-conjecture-part-2.html](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/05/r-and-the-collatz-conjecture-part-2.html)

Comment: `google R collatz efficient` - first 2 hits - should help :) got no idea about R

Comment: Unfortunately not really. I have seen those links before. They don't even attempt to construct explicitly the sequence of numbers in the conjecture. They just update a counter to get the length of the sequence(s). They run for a vector of arguments. Nevertheless, very interesting. Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was curious to see how a C++ implementation through `Rcpp` would compare to your two base R approaches. Here are my results.

First let's define a function `collatz_Rcpp` that returns the Hailstone sequence for a given integer `n`. The (non-recursive) implementation was adapted from [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:C%2B%2B).

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
    std::vector<int> collatz_Rcpp(int i) {
        std::vector<int> v;
        while(true) {
            v.push_back(i);
            if (i == 1) break;
            i = (i % 2) ? (3 * i + 1) : (i / 2);
        }
        return v;
    }
")
```

We now run a `microbenchmark` analysis using both your base R and the `Rcpp` implementation. We calculate the Hailstone sequences for the first 10000 integers

```
# base R implementation
collatz_R <- function(n) {
    # construct the entire Collatz path starting from n
    if (n==1) return(1)
    if (n %% 2 == 0) return(c(n, collatz(n/2)))
    return(c(n, collatz(3*n + 1)))
}

# "updated" base R implementation
collatz_R_updated <-function(n) {
  stopifnot(n >= 1)
  # define a vector without specifying the length
  x = c()
  i = 1
  while (n > 1) {
    x[i] = n
    i = i + 1
    n = ifelse(n %% 2, 3*n + 1, n/2)
  }
  x[i] = 1
  # now "cut" the vector
  dim(x) = c(i)
  return(x)
}

library(microbenchmark)
n <- 10000
res <- microbenchmark(
    baseR = sapply(1:n, collatz_R),
    baseR_updated = sapply(1:n, collatz_R_updated),
    Rcpp = sapply(1:n, collatz_Rcpp))

res
#         expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max
#        baseR   65.68623   73.56471   81.42989   77.46592   83.87024  193.2609
#baseR_updated 3861.99336 3997.45091 4240.30315 4122.88577 4348.97153 5463.7787
#         Rcpp   36.52132   46.06178   51.61129   49.27667   53.10080  168.9824

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(res)
```

[image]

The (non-recursive) `Rcpp` implementation seems to be around 30% faster than the original (recursive) base R implementation. The "updated" (non-recursive) base R implementation is significantly slower than the original (recursive) base R approach (the `microbenchmark` takes around 10 minutes to finish on my MacBook Air due to `baseR_updated`).

Comment: Wow, fascinating results. Many thanks. Now, I try to keep away from C++ as it adds yet another layer of complexity. I am very surprised by the differences between baseR and baseR_updated. I assumed baseR_updated to be faster than baseR. So baseR wins both for efficiency and elegance (over baseR_updated...)

Comment: Thanks for an interesting question @tschm. I guess the conclusion is that the recursive algorithm (`baseR`) is very fast, despite dynamically growing a vector in R. The `Rcpp` approach is not recursive, and is significantly faster than the equivalent base R approach `baseR_updated`. A recursive `Rcpp` version would probably be the winner;-)

Comment: I guess the next stop will be caching in particular if you compute 10000 sequences as you do....

Comment: I guess it's not trivial to cache a function in R. I could do m_f<-memoise(f) but in this case  the recursive calls of f in f are taking advantage of caching...