# Trying to find reason for execution time differences

Tags: r, performance

I wrote the code below to calculate Collatz sequences.  The basic algorithm steps are nearly identical to the code used in the library "[collatz](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/collatz/index.html)" available at CRAN. (the source tarball is [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/collatz_1.0.0.tar.gz) ) However, my hack code runs 10 to 50 times slower than the library's `hailstone_sequence` function.
I'm at a loss as to why, unless perhaps storing re-used constants via `lockBinding` makes a difference.  Can anyone take a look at the two sets of code and suggest what is causing the difference?  I've looked at the results of running `Rprof` and there's nothing obvious there.

{{ my code follows}}

```
collatz<-function(x, div=2, mul=3, add= 1, maxKnown=1, maxiter = 1000) {
y <- as.bigz(x[1])  #silent dumping
maxKnown <- as.bigz(floor(maxKnown))
cyclic = FALSE

for (jj in 2:maxiter) {
    
    y[[jj]] <- collatz_fun(y[[jj-1]],div,mul,add)
   # bigz/bigz returns a bigq even if that bigq has denominator 1
    # so we do a divq, "%/%", instead of div, to just get the bigz.
    if (y[[jj]] <= maxKnown   ) break 
    if(any(y[[jj]] == y[[1:(jj-1)]]))   {
        cyclic = TRUE
        break
    }
}
    if (jj >= maxiter)  warning('not converged (yet)')
    return(invisible(list(y = y, div = div, mul=mul, add= add, cyclic = cyclic) ) )
}

collatz_fun <- function(n, d, m, a){
    if (n%%d ==0 ) ( n %/% d ) else (m*n) +a
}
```

Comment: Just as a convenience, would you mind linking directly to the code you want us to compare to?

Comment: @GregorThomas the code is the source for the package link I provided.  I'll add a link to the source tarball as well.

Comment: Without digging so deep in the code, i can see, as you say, that an [environment](https://github.com/Skenvy/Collatz/blob/main/R/R/utils.R)  here is storing known sequences.

Comment: And assuming you've seen this [collatz discussion - Rcpp v Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635518/collatz-conjecture-in-r).

Comment: Following the github link on the CRAN package page, [here's the relevant function on github](https://github.com/Skenvy/Collatz/blob/main/R/R/hailstone_sequence.R#L51) so folks can look at it without downloading the package.

Comment: In fact, it's almost certainly the stored data.  I compared the two funcs with an input of  `fooint <-as.bigz('1111111111111111111111111111111111')` and my `collatz` function was faster!

Comment: Is it faster in the long run, as `fooint` goes to 1K, 10K, 100K in `length(`? And I ask out of curiosity as I try to follow your `bigz` explorations and haplessly learn something.

Comment: @Chris  I can run some `microbenchmark` tests & post up the results "soon" . Keep in mind that some very large numbers converge wicked fast, so it's important to pick a starting point that has a reasonably long sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was fooling myself!  For a few specific starting values, e.g., 737 ,  `hailstone_sequence` is faster.  However, in general my "collatz" code is faster.  Here's a table showing the tictoc times (in milliseconds) for random numbers of increasing size.

```
   Collatz, ms hailstone, ms start                            
 [1,] "2"         "2"           "89"                             
 [2,] "7"         "8"           "505"                            
 [3,] "10"        "13"          "4760"                           
 [4,] "5"         "8"           "46125"                          
 [5,] "57"        "89"          "706047"                         
 [6,] "52"        "77"          "7426598"                        
 [7,] "114"       "179"         "71693193"                       
 [8,] "76"        "128"         "195808257"                      
 [9,] "75"        "111"         "4082229980"                     
[10,] "89"        "133"         "29816905510"                    
[11,] "56"        "86"          "850451975896"                   
[12,] "240"       "390"         "5056177278457"                  
[13,] "179"       "288"         "23497279632257"                 
[14,] "133"       "217"         "667081939494479"                
[15,] "183"       "286"         "8724848384524922"               
[16,] "126"       "199"         "20376642404589490"              
[17,] "175"       "271"         "195397921609459067"             
[18,] "96"        "146"         "9068592584569983840"            
[19,] "203"       "317"         "98435723276783667011"           
[20,] "189"       "288"         "906945269554050299597"          
[21,] "586"       "934"         "1942663519120549652842"         
[22,] "288"       "414"         "32708032219025335530871"        
[23,] "331"       "459"         "815908776331672807666938"       
[24,] "379"       "581"         "6894029370205376937364345"      
[25,] "811"       "1182"        "49809117889125237920557852"     
[26,] "415"       "605"         "583415680232489269692462895"    
[27,] "559"       "793"         "9220767227146002168685568453"   
[28,] "733"       "1082"        "60679473842196546847954821109"  
[29,] "894"       "1228"        "698657027947326650828429401951" 
[30,] "1320"      "1932"        "8336688931823299843178876023479"
```